# chrome fires change event twice after enter key pressed and blur event

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, onchange, blur

I have a text `<input>` and when it is filed I want to fire the change event. The change event is fired by:
1. clicking outside the text field (so it loses focus) or
2. by pressing enter key (so the text field stays focused)

I don't want the text field focused so I use `.blur()` jQuery for this:

```
$(document).on("change", "input.quantity", function()
{   
    alert('Changed!');
    $(this).blur(); 
});
```

When I test it in Firefox all goes well
but when i test it in chrome, change event fires twice and I get two alerts.

It only happens if enter key is pressed.

If I remove the `$(this).blur();` change event fires just once.

The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rqFAH/)

This is probably a chrome bug, but if anyone has an idea how to work around this, it would be a great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead, not a proper solution, but will fix the issue you are facing:

```
$(document).on("change", "input.quantity", function(e)
{
    alert('Changed!');
    var $ele = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {$ele.blur();}, 50);
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqFAH/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is adequate enough